# ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row even though subqueries returns one row

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I am running this query on oracle database

```
UPDATE table1 SET col1=NULL,col2=NULL,col3=(SELECT col1 FROM table2 
WHERE col2='this') WHERE col4=(SELECT col1 FROM table3 WHERE 
col2='something');
```

and it gives following error even though those two subqueries return single value

**ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row**

So I ran two subqueries separately and used those values in query like this and it was sucessful

```
UPDATE table1 SET col1=NULL,col2=NULL,col3='value1' WHERE 
col4='some_value';
```

I can't figure out why is it throwing error when I am using subqueries

Comment: Show us some sample table data that can reproduce the error. Take a look at [mcve].

Comment: I finally found the issue. Its because I am inserting into table2 the value that already exists and so the subqueries are returning multiple rows

Comment: And that is why Nature gave us [unique key constraints](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/clauses002.htm#SQLRF52180).

Answer (score 1):

You would not get that error if the subqueries returned only one value.  I trust Oracle on this.

Phrase your query like this:

```
UPDATE table1
    SET col1 = NULL,
        col2 = NULL,
        col3 = (SELECT col1 FROM table2 WHERE col2 = 'this' AND rownum = 1)
    WHERE col4 IN (SELECT col1 FROM table3 WHERE col2 = 'something');
```

Comment: *"Does errors occur in oracle due to phrasing? "*. Not exactly. If Gordon's version of your query works it means your subquery `SELECT col1 FROM table2 WHERE col2 = 'this'` returns **more than one row** and/or `SELECT col1 FROM table3 WHERE col2 = 'something'` does. This version artificially restricts the first subquery to one row by restricting on ROWNUM; that is it guarantees the subquery returns one row but makes no promises about which row. The IN clause handles multiple rows in subquery. Whether that matters depends the details of your data and your business logic, which only you know.

Answer (score 1):

Mmm.. I firmly believe your subqueries are definitely returning more than one row. Run them independently and check:

```
SELECT col1 FROM table2 WHERE col2='this'
SELECT col1 FROM table3 WHERE col2='something'
```

If you can sling together some test case that proves me wrong, I'll file a bug with Oracle immediately

Easy way to ensure your subquery only ever returns one row is to max the result:

```
UPDATE table1 
SET col1=NULL,col2=NULL,col3=(SELECT MAX(col1) FROM table2 WHERE col2='this') 
WHERE col4 = (SELECT MAX(col1) FROM table3 WHERE col2='something')
```

In APC's comment he makes a very valid point:

It is nearly 100% certain that you are incorrect in your assertion that your subqueries only return one row. Oracle has managed to find more than one row to provide. As there are most likely two rows, you should invest some effort in considering whether there are ever any cases that DO return multiple rows, and in those cases *which of the returned rows do you want?* Do you want the latest? The earliest? The employeeid with the lowest salary? The subquery MUST be coded to answer this question. It shouldn't rely on `table3` only ever containing one row where `col2` is "something" because data changes; people with query tools poke at it all the time and production systems fall over in obscure ways. Think about the hard longevity of the solution you're arranging

Comment: Obviously the problem is that one or other (or both) of the subqueries returns more than one row. Your proposed solution would make the error go away but doesn't necessarily solve the problem. It depends on the OP's data and the business rule they are trying to enforce (neither of which is detailed in the question).

Comment: I appreciate this, but the OP is adamant their queries only contain one row, and the queries themselves don't make any effort to ensure *it is the right row* (such as the most recent etc) so it seems it doesn't actually matter which of the multiple rows the subqueries provide. I'm sure they will return when the update starts acting wierd, but my thanks for you to spur me into airing this particular point; your suggestion that there is a larger problem here is absolutely correct and most astute and I've added to my answer to discuss it

Comment: In a recent comment on their question the OP confesses that they have been inserting duplicate data into `table2` 8-)

Comment: I like it when SO questions make me laugh - sometimes the place can lack the humor of a more typical forum style community :D